# Typo in IntelliJ manual?

Tags: intellij-idea

From IntelliJ 14 help:

> There are certain cases when IntelliJ IDEA will not stop at a
>   breakpoint. Consider the following situation: Two breakpoints are set
>   at the different methods of a class, and there suspend policy is set
>   to All. When one of the breakpoints is hit, some step actions are
>   performed. If at the time of stepping another thread hits the second
>   breakpoint, **profuct** will not stop there.

I thought it's a typo but "product will not stop there" still doesn't make sense.

I'm pretty sure they mean that the execution will not stop there, but I was wondering what the word there was supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word was supposed to be "IntelliJ IDEA" (it's a macro which gets replaced with the actual product name when the help is generated).

Comment: I guess since you're from JetBrains you must know... thanks :)